# Polymer index property of type object with another property

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a custom element, `x-custom`, that has a property, `object`, that is an Object.

I have another property, `name`, that I want to use to *index* `object`, to put data from other custom elements under a specific property of `object`.

Something like the following is the end goal:

```
<other-custom-element data="{{object.{{name}}}}"></other-custom-element>
...

name: {
  type: String,
},

object: {
  type: Object,
  value: {}
}
```

So, in the example, if the value of `name` is "prop1", then the data from `other-custom-element` would be placed into `object.prop1`.

**EDIT:**

So, I've updated my code and have gotten a bit closer, but still not quite all the way. The following example code is much closer to my actual code, so maybe it'll help in answering the question:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[locations]]" as="location">
  <get-data-at-location
    location="[[location]]"
    data="[[_resolveRef(location)]]">
  </get-data-at-location>

  <h5>Data at location: [[location]]</h5>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_resolveRef(location)]]" as="data">
    <p>Data: {{data.value}}</p>
    <p>Time: {{data.time}}</p>
  </template>
</template>

...

alldata: {
  type: Object
  value: {}
},

_resolveRef: function(location) {
  return this.alldata[location];
}
```

I'm trying to basically pass a reference to a specific element of `alldata` with `_resolveRef()`, but I think there may be a scoping issue. I get the following error (say, if `location` is equal to "some_location"):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'some_location' of undefined
```

So, for some reason it doesn't seem to know about "alldata", even though it is a property of the custom element. Hopefully that's enough for a Polymer whiz to help :)

**EDIT 2:**

Some sample data to make the final goal more clear.

Say that locations is an array consisting of the following strings:

```
locations: {
  type: Array,
  value: ['location1', 'location2']
}
```

And say that the `<get-data-at-location>` element returns the following data for each individual location:

```
<get-data-at-location
  location=[[location]] //'location1'
  data={{}}>            //[{value: 4, time: 0}, {value: 5, time: 1}]
</get-data-at-location>

<get-data-at-location
  location=[[location]] //'location2'
  data={{}}>            //[{value: 10, time: 1}, {value: 11, time: 2}]
</get-data-at-location>
```

After all is said and done, I would like `alldata` to have the following information:

```
alldata: {
  location1: [{value: 4, time: 0}, {value: 5, time: 1}],
  location2: [{value: 10, time: 1}, {value: 11, time: 2}]
}
```

So, I would like the object `alldata` shared across all instances of the dom-repeat so that they can all place data into *their respective property* (which is just the string value of *location*) of the overall object.

**EDIT 3:**

Tried something new. Rather than `_resolveRef(location)` as a way to return a pointer to the location where `<get-data-from-location>` should store the data that it gets, I just used the following syntax: `{{alldata[location]}}` and things worked better, but still not perfect.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[locations]]" as="location">
  <get-data-at-location
    location="[[location]]"
    data="{{alldata[location]}}">
  </get-data-at-location>

  <h5>Data at location: [[location]]</h5>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{alldata[location]}}" as="data">
    <p>Data: {{data.value}}</p>
    <p>Time: {{data.time}}</p>
  </template>
</template>

...

alldata: {
  type: Object
  value: {}
}
```

So, this appears to work! Until I realized that the `alldata` that the data is being bound to is *not* the `alldata` of the custom element - it appears to be bound to the scope of the first `dom-repeat`, which the second `dom-repeat` has access to.

So basically, if I was to use this custom element within another page and bind to `alldata`, it doesn't work:

```
<x-custom alldata={{allData}}></x-custom>
<x-pretty-json object={{allData}}></x-pretty-json>
```

`<x-pretty-json>` just pretty-prints the provided object, and in this case it just prints empty brackets `{}`. So, closer (kind of), but still not quite there.

Comment: You can create function that receive the name and return the value that you want to use.

Comment: @Alon, thanks for the comment. Would that look something like `<other-custom-element data="_resolveObjectRef(name)"></other-custom-element>`...? Should it be wrapped in curly braces?

Comment: {{_resolveObjectRef(name)}}

Comment: Just a tip, you probably don't want to use `value: {}`, as this object will be shared across all instances of your element. If each instance of your element should have a different object for the default, you'll want this: `value: function () { return {}; }`

Comment: Also, just to get the basic debugging questions out of the way, are you 100% positive that alldata is defined to a value at the time of this dom-repeat running? Are you getting that data from a source that might be setting it to undefined?

Comment: @Dogs, thanks for the information. However, I think I do want `alldata` to be initialized to just `{}`, because I *do* want `alldata` to be shared across all instances in the om-repeat. I'll update the answer with some sample data and hopefully that will help clear things up.

Comment: To answer the debugging question, I had assumed that `alldata` was defined to a value at the time of the dom-repeat running as it is a property of the custom element, and is not getting (or, should not be) set from a different source.

Comment: Hmm, I've changed something to where I'm not receiving the `Uncaught TypeError` anymore, but `_resolveRef`, although it returns the pointer to the location where data *should* be stored, it doesn't seem to store the data in any way so that I can then retrieve it later.

Comment: @MandM Sorry, I think I wasn't sufficiently clear about the `value: {}` thing. If you use `{}` as the value, rather than a function that returns `{}` as the value, every single instance of your parent element ('x-custom' as you called it in your first example) will share an instance. The child elements will always get whichever copy is given to them by the parent, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: @Dogs, *ah*, understood. Yes, I definitely *don't* want instances of that object shared across different declarations of `<x-custom>`, so I will use the method you mentioned earlier. Unfortunately, the main question is still outstanding... any pointers there? :)

Comment: @Dogs, does the same need to be done in the case of initializing an array? I.e. `value: function(){ return []; }`?